Can I run a laptop with no OS from a bootable USB thumbdrive
I have a HP Stream 14  with windows 10 that's useless because windows takes up the entire 32 GB hard drive. Can I wipe it and run from a bootable thumb drive?

What OS do you plan to use? Linux, yes. Windows, no. But you can use mklink to move folders from C to a thumbdrive, so you can essentially create more space.

i got a 512 gig sd what if i put an OS on that and mounted it to the computer.

Windows won't like it. But you can move certain folders to that drive, and use mklink on the C drive to redirect it back to the external drive. Do note, you will have to configure to not boot from the drive and you must have it plugged in before starting the computer up.

There's no need to wipe that minuscule internal SSD to run Ubuntu or other Linux from an external drive; test the new OS before making any change to the internal drive. Also, the faster the external drive, the more responsive will be the OS.

In theory yes, although not every OS will run properly off a USB device as a "full installation". It also won't be fast.
Windows does not support this officially (other than the read-only WinPE and the no-longer-supported "Windows To Go"); you might need to image the existing installation to the USB disk, or try your luck with a manual installation using dism /apply-image. I've heard that it's possible but pretty fragile.
Something like Linux (Ubuntu, Mint, etc.) is a better option, assuming your required programs can run on it. You'll still need two USB disks (one to boot the "live installer" system and another as the installation target), but generally it should work just as well as from an internal disk. (It still won't be fast, though, and it can wear out USB sticks fast – try to use an actual "USB SSD".)

idk a whole lot about it i just got this to start learning programming and it didnt even have an OS to start with so i used a windows  disk to get it going but windows 10 is way too big for it. so i need something small. i was thinking linux lite but ill look into mint i hadnt heard of it .

Honestly, depending on what you need, you might be able to fit Linux and your IDE and some programming projects in those 32 GB and still have space left... (Though of course it highly depends on which Linux distribution, which desktop environment, which IDE, etc. – but the nice thing is that it largely doesn't stop you from trimming down unneeded parts.)

you mean like Windows dose. the Apps that come with it are a night mare to un install.

If you are planning to run Linux through USB Thumb Drive, it is quite possible. You can even setup persistence to save your data on that USB Thumb Drive.
In case you want to run Windows through USB Thumb, it may not be possible officially. Some workaround might help. But for Live OS over USB, I'll recommend Linux.

thank you what Distro do you recommend im trying to get into development  been learning python on my phone

any beginner friendly and stable distro like Linux Mint or Debian may help you. Just check the answer by @grawity_u1686 as he has described it in detail. Python will run on all Linux distro (I don't think there would be any distro which will be pain for python developers).
